# Symfony without javascript and tracking components

Tags: javascript, symfony, open-source

I would like to know if there is a possibility to use the Symfony framework without javascript? (or if there is a forked project...)

Indded, javascript being nowadays one of the best tool to track people and behaviours, which is incompatible with freedom (and in consequence democracy), I am looking for the use of libre technology (far away from the GAFAM ideologies) with Symfony.

Thank you in advance for the sharing of your opinions.

Comment: Hmmm.  Symfony is a php framework.  No Javascript unless you add it.  http://symfony.com/what-is-symfony

Comment: Indeed but an important set of bundles (i.e. easyadmin) comes with included javascript (hopefully fosuser does not :-p ).

Comment: Then, don't use bundles that require the use of JavaScript. :) Speaking of EasyAdminBundle, it should be possible to not load the JavaScript files shipped with the bundle and overwrite the parts that currently make use of JavaScript to work around it.

Comment: I understand your concerns but as of yet there have been no CONFIRMED reports that CIA/NSA/FBI/DIA/GSA etc agents have arrested and prosecuted any Symfony developers for NOT using javascript.  Of course the actual arrests have probably just been covered up but at some point you just need to take a risk.  Just stay away from microwave ovens and you should be okay.

Comment: Thank you @xabbuh: I will think about creating a easyadmin forked project.

@ Cerad: the use of javascript is for example widely used by google ("don't be evil") to monitor users actions (there is nothing to do with arrested people and microwaves, but about living in the real world :-p )

Comment: @Cerad, Symfony is a PHP framework with little javascript. It tells us to do so, for example here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Comment: I know I should leave well enough alone but I just can't help myself.  Are you saying that if I added the example form collection javascript code to my Symfony application that suddenly "evil google" would be able to monitor users actions?

Comment: @Cerad: Com'on Cerad, of course not. However, if we can provide an application 100% javascript-free, better the confidence we may gain. That said, you are right: Symfony is a php framework unless we add javascript. Several bundles on their side use javascript which is a pity.